# How to add another section based on row input (alphabet) in UITableView - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am a new iOS programming. I am creating a sample app which similar to `contact` app. I wonder how that real application works. For example, Our tableview display names based on alphabet like name starts with `A` will stays in `A` section and `B` will stays in `B` section and so on. And when user input some names which not exist in section then, new section will be auto created. I wonder how can i achieve something like this.

This is how i created UITableView programmatically. Not using storyboard

```
private let cellId = "cellId"
private let array = ["Aname", "Bname", "Cname", "Dname"]
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
}
```

Here is how i custom display data

```
// Table View
```

extension ContactListController {

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let label = UILabel()
    label.backgroundColor = .gray
    label.text = "A"
    return label

}
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


    return array.count


}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)


    cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]



    return cell

}
```

}

For my desire output i would like to display name starts with `A` should be in `A` section and so on...

Thank for your explanation.

Comment: You can check when there is no data to display mean section count 0 then you can pass one new section for such case.

Comment: Show your code. It depends on how the sections are implemented.

Comment: Sir! I have update my question @vadian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is the method `Dictionary(grouping: by:)`

- Create an array for the sections (`keys`), a dictionary for the names (`people`) and make `array` mutable

  ```
  var keys = [String]()
  var people = [String : [String]]()

  private var array = ["Aname", "Bname", "Cname", "Dname"]
  ```
- Add a method to group the data

  ```
  func groupData()
  {
      people = Dictionary(grouping: array, by: {String($0.first!)})
      keys = people.keys.sorted()
      tableView.reloadData()
  }
  ```

  If you want to restrict the grouping to consider only capital letters write

  ```
  people = Dictionary(grouping: array, by: {$0.range(of: "^[A-Z]", options: .regularExpression) != nil ? String($0.first!) : "Unknown"})
  ```
- in `viewDidLoad` call the method

  ```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
      groupData()
  }
  ```
- Instead of `viewForHeaderInSection` implement `titleForHeaderInSection`

  ```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
      return keys[section]
  }
  ```
- The other relevant table view datasource and delegate methods are

  ```
  override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
      return keys.count
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      let letter = keys[section]
      return people[letter]!.count
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
      let letter = keys[indexPath.section]
      let item = people[letter]![indexPath.row]
      cell.textLabel!.text = item
      return cell
  }
  ```

To add a new item append the name to `array` and call `groupData`

If you want a more sophisticated solution with animations when the sections and rows are inserted you have to write the logic yourself. The design array for the keys and dictionary for the names can be used as well as a custom struct including the letter index and an array for the rows.

Comment: Thank sir for this wonderful explanation. I run the code and work fine for me. But could you please explain me the `groupData` function with the first 2 lines of code?

Comment: The grouping API is described in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2995342-init). It creates a dictionary from the array with the first letters as keys.

Comment: I have another doubt. I want to group section which only A...Z only if user input like number or something it should be display in one unique section which user input beside from A...Z  with some symbol like # or whatever ....

Comment: Thank you sir! now i understand. Thank for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You should gouup data contact before show in table view,Each key will a section in tableview, i have sample code group data:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSArray *arrNameContact = @[@"Aname",@"Bname",@"Cname",@"Dname",@"Dname1",@"Aname1",@"Ename1",@"Bname1"];
    NSMutableArray *arrKey = [self getArrayKeyFromArrayName:arrNameContact];

    NSMutableDictionary *dict =@{}.mutableCopy;

    for (NSString *key in arrKey) {
        NSMutableArray *arrContactWithKey = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (NSString *name in arrNameContact) {
            if ([name hasPrefix:key]) {
                [arrContactWithKey addObject:name];
            }
        }
        [dict setObject:arrContactWithKey forKey:key];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",dict);
}

// Get All alphabet
- (NSMutableArray *) getArrayKeyFromArrayName:(NSArray *)arrName {
    NSMutableArray *arrKey = @[].mutableCopy;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrName.count; i++) {
        NSString *strFirstCharacter = [arrName[i] substringToIndex:1];
        if (arrKey.count == 0) {
            [arrKey addObject:strFirstCharacter];
        } else {
            if (![self checkItemExistKey:strFirstCharacter inArray:arrKey]) {
                [arrKey addObject:strFirstCharacter];
            }
        }
    }
    return arrKey;
}

- (BOOL) checkItemExistKey:(NSString *) key inArray:(NSArray *)arrKey {
    for (NSString *keyCheck in arrKey) {
        if ([keyCheck isEqualToString:key]) {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

result after group data:

```
Printing description of dict:
{
    A =     (
        Aname,
        Aname1
    );
    B =     (
        Bname,
        Bname1
    );
    C =     (
        Cname
    );
    D =     (
        Dname,
        Dname1
    );
    E =     (
        Ename1
    );
}
```

Good luck!